# Obstruction for a manifold to admit a periodic Ricci flow

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow, geometric-constructions, ricci-curvature

Let M be a (compact) smooth manifold. What kind of obstruction exist for M to admit a metric whose Ricci  flow is a t-periodic flow?

Comment: Doesn't Perelman's [entropy formula](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211159) rule out periodic flows that are not stationary?

Comment: @WillieWong  Thank  you for your comment  and Prelman work. I was not aware of Perelman work.

Comment: @WillieWong  The only thing I had already heard was "Prelman solved Poincare conjecture via Ricci flow" Then I serach for  definition of Ricci flow I realized it is a  1 parameter family of metric  with certain differential equation. So I posed the question when is this 1 parameter periodic. I was some how inspired by obstructions for  manifold to be  an Einstein manifold. I thank you again for informing me of the Entropy formula.